# JQuery Autocomplete remote data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I've got it to work, and I have looked online and through the documentation, it's not very useful for some reason!

Given this code that works as expected:

```
<input type="text" id="color_input" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#color_input').autocomplete('autoComplete.aspx');
</script>
```

What I can't figure out is how what the user has typed is sent to the autoComplete.aspx page?  For example if I type in 'Thoma' how is 'Thoma' sent to the processing page?

Does it send it via querystring?  Or post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a GET request with a `q=Thoma` in the querystring as mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions).

If you turn on Firebug or HTTP Headers you should be able to trap the outgoing requests and examine them.

You change the request to use POST by setting the [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Options)